# Unable to update date and time fields into Mysql record

Tags: php, mysql, datetime

I need some help with this :

I have a MySql database which has several text field and 2 sets each of date and time fields. The problem is while one set of date and time field gets updated correctly, the other set does not. The four fields are:

- complaint_date
- complaint_time
- admin_date
- admin_time

The four fields take date and time fields through date function. While the last two get updated into the table the first two display no value (all 0's to be precise). The name of the database is complaint_data and the table name is complaints.

The code for complaint_date and complaint_time

```
$user="root";
$password="";
$database="complaint_data";
$localhost="localhost";
mysql_connect($localhost,$user,$password);
@mysql_select_db($database) or die("Unable to open database");

$user=$_SESSION['staffnumber'];

$type=$_SESSION['input'];
$catg=$_SESSION['input1'];
$text=$_POST['Comment'];
$status="open";
$date=date_create();
$_SESSION['cid']=date_timestamp_get($date);
$cid=$_SESSION['cid'];

$cmpdate=date("Y-m-d");
date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Kolkata");
$cmptime=date("H:i:s");

$query="INSERT INTO complaints (`username`, `type`, `category`, `subcategory`, `comment`, `priority`, `status`, `complaintid`) 
 VALUES('$user','$type','$catg','$subcatg','$text','$p','$status','$cid')";
$result=mysql_query($query);

$query1="UPDATE complaints SET `complaint_date`='$cmpdate' , complaint_time='$cmptime' WHERE complaintid='$cid' ";
$result1=mysql_query($query1);

mysql_close();
header('Location:main.html');
```

TIA :)

Comment: Why do not use now() funcion of mysql ?

Comment: Do you update admin_date and admin_time after executing this code? If yes, then maybe you have something in your other code that correctly updates admin related fields but overwrites complaint_date and complaint_time

Comment: @dadda, first execute your update query in mysql editor and check that there is everything ok or not..this is the best way of debugging the mysql query.

Comment: Just note, use MySQLi or PDO. Its more secure.

Comment: @rohit it works in the editor but the PHP code fails.

Comment: @Marco Mura would you explain the use of now() in php ?

Comment: @dadda, Please use `sleep()` function between two queries and `pass time in seconds` as a parameter in this function. i.e, `sleep(5);` this function means that your second query will execute after 5 seconds of the execution of first query.

Comment: @dadda the now function will as example insert into a datetime the now moment(now = timestamp or datetime of the moment when inserting/updating), it works even on update.

Answer (score 0):

Actually your date format is not same with mysql format so try to use below code.

```
$date = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
$date = strtotime($date);
$cmpdate = date('Y-m-d',$date);
$cmptime = date('H:i:s',$date);

$query1="UPDATE complaints SET `complaint_date`='$cmpdate' , complaint_time='$cmptime' WHERE complaintid='$cid' ";
$result1=mysql_query($query1);
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Folks , it worked. Thanks all for your inputs. There was no mistake except that another part of the code was inhibiting the insert function. So silly of me to have missed it out !

Thanks again :)